# How to force 0.00001 on plot to display as $10^{-5}$

Tags: plotting

Consider specific example of plotting generated data:

```
f[x_, y_] = 10^11*y^2*(Exp[-100 y^2/x^6] - Exp[-140 y^2/x^6]);
plot = RegionPlot[f[x, 10^(y/2)] >= 1, {x, 0.1, 10}, {y, -7, 1}]
plotdata = {#[[1]], 10^#[[2]]} & /@ 
   Partition[Flatten[Cases[Normal@plot, Line[x_] :> x, Infinity]], 2];
ListLogLinearPlot[plotdata, PlotRange -> {{0.1, 10}, {10^-7, 10^-5}}, 
 Ticks -> {Automatic, {N[10^-7], N[5*10^-7], N[10^-6], N[5*10^-6], 
    N[7*10^-6], N[10^-5]}}]
```

All the numbers for the y labels are displayed as I want - $5\cdot 10^{-6}$, $7\cdot 10^{-6}$, all the numbers after $10^{-5}$ are displayed in the form 0.000x. How to force them to displayed as $x\cdot 10^{-5}$?

Comment: Try to wrap with `ScientificForm`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using [`NumberForm`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/NumberForm.html) with  [`ExponentFunction`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ExponentFunction.html) option setting  `(# &)` seems to work:

```
 Ticks -> {Automatic, {#, NumberForm[#, ExponentFunction -> (# &)]} & /@
   {N[10^-7], N[5*10^-7], N[10^-6], N[5*10^-6], N[7*10^-6], N[10^-5]}}
```

gives

[image]